# Webpack - script configuration from HTML file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using Webpack for my project written in Typescript and I'd like to ask if there's a possibility to change eg. variables/objects embedded in my `bundle.js` file? I mean something like this (without Webpack is a prevalent approach).

My HTML file:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    MyScript.init({width: 500});
</scipt>
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './signature.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

You can make webpack automatically export `MyScript` by adding `libraryTarget: "umd"` and use `module.exports = MyScript` or `export MyScript`.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './signature.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        // add this:
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    }
}
```

and in your Script

```
var MyScript = {
    init: function (width) {
         if (width === undefined) {
               // set default width
               width = 400
         }
         // your code here
    }
}

module.exports = myScript
```

This way, your users can decide for themselves how they call your module.

**Further information:**

- [UMD (Universial Module Definition)](http://bob.yexley.net/umd-javascript-that-runs-anywhere/)
- [libraryTarget](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/)

**Old:**

Yes it is. This is not specifically related to webpack though. You want this:

```
window.MyScript = {
    init: function (width) {
         if (width === undefined) {
               // set default width
               width = 400
         }
         // your code here
    }
}
```

then, you can use it from your html script tag.

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    MyScript.init({width: 500});
</scipt>
```

As a property of the `window`-object, your code can be accessed from anywhere.

But please keep in mind that this defies the purpose of using javascript architectures you need webpack for. You want to prevent polluting the global scope which is one of the reasons to use module bundlers with umd/cjs/amd.

**Further information on `window`:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Comment: Thanks, it works! I just want to allow others to change a few basic settings of my app, so I hope it won't "pollute the global scope" so much.

Comment: by the way, you can also just set `libraryTarget: "umd"` in your output and module.export the `MyScript` object. This has a similar effects. I will edit my answer